# How would you clean this dictionary in Python?

Tags: python, dictionary, web-scraping

This is my first attempt building something non-web and involving logic coding.

Please take a look at this god-awful dictionary below:

```
  Messy_Dict=
    {
        'name': "['\\r\\n                  NASDAQ: BKEP\\r\\n          ']", 
        'underlying': "['1.12']", 
        'strike_prices_list': ["['2.50'", " '5.00'", " '7.50']"], 
        'call_bid': ["['\\r\\n0.05            '", " '\\r\\n0.00            '", " '\\r\\n0.00            ']"], 
        'put_ask': ["['\\r\\n2.10            '", " '\\r\\n4.50            '", " '\\r\\n7.00            ']"]
    }
```

What I want to do is clean up the unnecessary sub-strings within each dictionary value to get something like this:

```
Clean_Dict=
    {
        'name': "BKEP", 
        'underlying': "1.12", 
        'strike_prices_list': ["2.50", "5.00", "7.50"], 
        'call_bid': ["0.05", "0.00", "0.00"], 
        'put_ask': ["2.10", "4.50", "7.00"]
    }
```

I have managed to get from *Messy_Dict* to *Clean_Dict* but I used very barbaric means to do so. I will just say that it included a for loop and multiple strip(), replace('', '') methods. And it pains me to look at that block of code in my .py file.

So I guess, is there a more elegant method in performing the desired task of converting Messy_Dict to Clean_Dict? I feel as if I'm missing something here in my fundamentals.

### Edit

```
def parse(self, response):
        strike_prices_main = response.css('.highlight , .aright .strike-col').css('::text').extract()
        if not strike_prices_main:
            pass
        else:
            name = response.css('#instrumentticker::text').extract()
            strike_prices_list = response.css('.aright .strike-col').css('::text').extract()
            call_bid = response.css('.aright td:nth-child(5)').css('::text').extract()
            put_ask = response.css('.aright td:nth-child(14)').css('::text').extract()
            underlying = response.css('.pricewrap .bgLast').css('::text').extract()
            file.write('%s|%s|%s|%s|%s\n'%(name,underlying,strike_prices_list,call_bid,put_ask))
```

Using spiders to crawl!

Comment: have you tried iterating the keys, and for each value use regex to replace all offending characters?

Comment: the right question in this case is where "messy" dict comes from. It looks very much like JSON that was abused somehow to become this...Probably json response that was not handled properly?

Comment: How many for loops and regex statements would it take?

Comment: @buran i was scraping Yahoo Finance to get some data! And gosh, this got printed on my cmd prmt hahaha ouch

Comment: @LowaiisTan, So my guess is right and best approach would be to show your code that query Yahoo finance and get help with it. As it stands this is XY problem. You can get perfect formated valid JSON response from yahoo finance

Comment: @buran check edited answer! And wait, do they actually have nice clean JSON? hoho tell me more

Comment: Check the network traffic when you make the request. And here is my implementation from some years ago to download option chains https://github.com/boyank/yoc

Comment: For example https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/options/BKEP

Comment: @buran Okay your code is way too low level in abstraction for me! And thanks for the link, am taking a look

Comment: @ I don't know what you mean too low level in abstraction, but the point was to show you the json request. Anyway I didn't mean to suggest using my code as is...

Comment: @buran Oh no no, I mean you are using pure python and its library! Im using python frameworks and modules still, still a noob you see hahaha. Your repo was great! The query1 was a good advice too, im gonna use it in my project! Thnks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe like this:

```
import re
Messy_Dict= \
{
    'name': "['\\r\\n                  NASDAQ: BKEP\\r\\n          ']", 
    'underlying': "['1.12']", 
    'strike_prices_list': ["['2.50'", " '5.00'", " '7.50']"], 
    'call_bid': ["['\\r\\n0.05            '", " '\\r\\n0.00            '", " '\\r\\n0.00            ']"], 
    'put_ask': ["['\\r\\n2.10            '", " '\\r\\n4.50            '", " '\\r\\n7.00            ']"]
}
regexstr = "\\\\(r|n)|\s|\[|\]|\'|NASDAQ:"

dict_clean = {}
for k, v in Messy_Dict.items():
    if isinstance(v, list):
        list_clean = []
        for el in v:            
            el_clean = re.sub(regexstr, "", el)
            list_clean.append(el_clean)
        dict_clean[k] = list_clean
    else:
        dict_clean[k] = re.sub(regexstr, "", v)
dict_clean
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use regular expressions.

Example:

```
import re

messy_dict = {
    'name': "['\\r\\n                  NASDAQ: BKEP\\r\\n          ']", 
    'underlying': "['1.12']", 
    'strike_prices_list': ["['2.50'", " '5.00'", " '7.50']"], 
    'call_bid': ["['\\r\\n0.05            '", " '\\r\\n0.00            '", " '\\r\\n0.00            ']"], 
    'put_ask': ["['\\r\\n2.10            '", " '\\r\\n4.50            '", " '\\r\\n7.00            ']"]
}

for key in messy_dict:
    stripfunc = lambda x: re.sub('[^\d\.]', '', str(x))
    if type(messy_dict[key]) is list:
        messy_dict[key] = [stripfunc(x) for x in messy_dict[key]]
    else:
        messy_dict[key] = stripfunc(messy_dict[key])

print(messy_dict)
```

Explanation: [^ ] matches anything that is NOT in the set. \d is for numeric values and the backslash escapes the dot. Using str(val) to make strings out of the lists.

Output: `{'name': '', 'underlying': '1.12', 'strike_prices_list': ['2.50', '5.00', '7.50'], 'call_bid': ['0.05', '0.00', '0.00'], 'put_ask': ['2.10', '4.50', '7.00']}`

Edit: just noticed that you also want to keep the dot. Updated the code.

Comment: Woops, I haven't. Fixed.

Comment: Would prefer a bit more accuracy in exchange for less concision!

Comment: Huh, it generates the result you asked for?